# Encrypted output is different in openssl command and openssl C Program

Tags: c, linux, openssl, aes

I wrote a simple openssl program to perform 'AES-128-CBC' encryption.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>


#define KEY_SIZE 16
#define IV_SIZE 16

void handleErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}


void hexdump(const void* data, size_t size) {
    char ascii[17];
    size_t i, j;
    ascii[16] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%02X ", ((unsigned char*)data)[i]);
        if (((unsigned char*)data)[i] >= ' ' && ((unsigned char*)data)[i] <= '~') {
            ascii[i % 16] = ((unsigned char*)data)[i];
        } else {
            ascii[i % 16] = '.';
        }
        if ((i+1) % 8 == 0 || i+1 == size) {
            printf(" ");
            if ((i+1) % 16 == 0) {
                printf("|  %s \n", ascii);
            } else if (i+1 == size) {
                ascii[(i+1) % 16] = '\0';
                if ((i+1) % 16 <= 8) {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                for (j = (i+1) % 16; j < 16; ++j) {
                    printf("   ");
                }
                printf("|  %s \n", ascii);
            }
        }
    }
}


int encrypt_file(void)
{   
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    char plain_text[12] = "Hello World";
    size_t plaintext_len = 12;
    unsigned char *ciphertext = NULL;
    int ciphertext_maxlen = plaintext_len + EVP_CIPHER_block_size(EVP_aes_128_cbc())*2 - 1;
    int len  = 0, ciphertext_len = 0;   
    ciphertext = (unsigned char *)malloc(ciphertext_maxlen * sizeof(unsigned char));


    unsigned char key[KEY_SIZE]= {0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11};
    unsigned char iv[IV_SIZE] = {0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22};
    hexdump(key, 16);
    hexdump(iv, 16);

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plain_text, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();

    ciphertext_len = len;
    if( EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len) != 1 ) 
        handleErrors();

    ciphertext_len += len;

    printf("ciphertext len:%d\n", ciphertext_len);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    hexdump(ciphertext, ciphertext_len);
    free(ciphertext);
    return 0;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    encrypt_file();
    return 0;
}
```

When i am running this program it's generating cipher text.

```
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  |  ................ 
22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22  22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22  |  """""""""""""""" 
ciphertext len:16
4F 55 95 1F D9 A6 34 F1  2F 90 06 2B 82 F8 C2 19  |  OU....4./..+....
```

I am trying to verify whether my C code is working fine or not by passing the same parameters to openssl commands

```
jamal@jamal-VirtualBox:~$ echo "Hello World" > plaintext.txt
jamal@jamal-VirtualBox:~$ cat plaintext.txt 
Hello World
jamal@jamal-VirtualBox:~$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in plaintext.txt -K '11111111111111111111111111111111' -iv '22222222222222222222222222222222' -out openssl_enc.txt -p 
salt=F3753875307F0000
key=11111111111111111111111111111111
iv =22222222222222222222222222222222
jamal@jamal-VirtualBox:~$ hexdump openssl_enc.txt 
0000000 ea60 4e8e a289 ea50 ee19 0edc 81ea 557d
0000010
```

Why is the cipher bytes generated by C code not same as the one generated by openssl command. Am i missing anything in Code?

Comment: Because the input is not the same.  Use `echo -n` if you don't want to add a newline.

Comment: After changing size_t plaintext_len = 12; to size_t plaintext_len = 11; its working and output is same

Comment: You can change `size_t plaintext_len = 11;` by `size_t plaintext_len = strlen(plain_text);`